# Showing app errors for facebook credits api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-credits

Recently i started to convert my payment methods in my canvas app to Facebook credits. 
The thing is that i have some validation and verification done on my backend and i must return an error back to the user. 
I saw the Facebook's PHP callback implementation (pretty ugly btw lol ... compared to the other APIs) and i saw a comment stating that there is some kind of error and comment support although i can't seem to find how to return human readable error from my app back to the user. 

Here is how my thing goes

- User finds a needed extra and press the buy button
- I call the proper FBJS method
- Facebook asks my callback for item information and i return it.. price image name desc etc etc
- Then Facebook sends the first payments_status_update which is "placed"
- This is where i check for any errors. If i find something i want to print it out back to the user with refunded or canceled status

Honestly, I've tried everything but i just can't get it to use my comment instead of some silly error message. Some of my extras require certain buildings to be built before being bought but i can't notify the user :/ I don't want to make an AJAX request to my php backend to find whether this user can buy this extra or cannot and if he can then i call the fbjs proper methods. This is silly. Is there someway to evade it ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to update Facebook's canceled dialog with custom messaging.

After the user clicks OK in the cancel dialog, Facebook will still invoke your JS callback. You can capture this and appropriately message the user.

However, I still think the best user experience will consider what the user can purchase before the user attempts to purchase.